# A Rainbow of Flavors

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to this puzzle is a single word.

[image: A bunch of macarons]

Comment: I object, it can't be a rainbow if there are only 6 colors!

Comment: Assuming M Oehm's answer is correct, this is a beautiful puzzle.

Comment: @LordFarquaad It is correct indeed, and thank you :-)

Comment: Would the `rebus` tag also fit here or not? Besides, I already looked at @MOehm 's accepted answer, and I must say this puzzle was much more clever than I had anticipated! Really well done! DVL2 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: I removed the rebus tag because the answer (which I already knew from somewhere else) didn't look like what I commonly think is a rebus, though rebuses are really hard to define. Maybe ask on meta if you think rebus is a good fit here so we don't end up in an edit war.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is ...

> ... **salted**, one of the basic flavours.

Each of the six pictures ...

> ... has three pieces of information: The colour, number and flavour of the macarons. The colour determines the order of the images (although for aesthetic reasons, they are already in order), the number determines which letter to take from the flavour:
>
>  **S** *red* **3** ra**s**pberry
>  **A** *orange* **3** or**a**nges
>  **L** *yellow* **1** **l**emon
>  **T** *green* **4** pis**t**acchio
>  **E** *blue* **6** blueb**e**rry
>  **D** *violet* **6** laven**d**er

Comment: That is a really clever answer to a really clever puzzle! :D

Answer (score 2):

is it

> skittles! taste the rainbow!

Comment: No, no slogans are involved in the answer.